# Unity C# loadimage from byte

Tags: unity-game-engine, decode, encode, texture2d, loadimage

Game has a file generator (make levels files).
I update an asset, add functional of save jpg to file.
After that game read file and make image from this.

My steps:

1. settings.imageCode = coloredTexture.EncodeToJPG();
2. Save to file:

```
if (settings.rastr)
     {
         bytes.AddRange(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(settings.imageCode.Length));
         bytes.AddRange(settings.imageCode);
     }
```

3. Start game. Game read levels files (part about img):

```
 private byte[] GetSprite() private byte[] GetSprite()
            {
                int length = GetNextInt();

                ArraySegment<byte> byteImage = new ArraySegment<byte>(levelFileBytes, byteIndex, length);
                
                byteIndex += length;
                int count = byteImage.Count;

                return byteImage.Array;
            }
```

4. Try create sprite and add it to GO:

```
private void CreateRastrImage(LevelFileData levelFileData)
        {
            GameObject imageObj = new GameObject("Rastr");
            RectTransform containerRectT = imageObj.AddComponent<RectTransform>();

            containerRectT.SetParent(transform, false);

            // Expand to fill
            containerRectT.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
            containerRectT.anchorMin = Vector2.zero;
            containerRectT.anchorMax = Vector2.one;
            containerRectT.offsetMax = Vector2.zero;
            containerRectT.offsetMin = Vector2.zero;

            Image sprite = imageObj.AddComponent<Image>();
            Texture2D spriteColor = new Texture2D(levelFileData.imageWidth, levelFileData.imageHeight);
            //ImageConversion.LoadImage(spriteColor, levelFileData.rastrBytes);
            spriteColor.LoadImage(levelFileData.rastrBytes);
            Sprite fileSptire = Sprite.Create(spriteColor, new Rect(0f, 0f, spriteColor.width, spriteColor.height), new Vector2(0f, 0f));
            sprite.sprite = fileSptire;
        }
```

5. Result:[red question mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiolb.png)

About result, source img its this jpg file: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRvBm.jpg)
Use jpg (RGB24), also try another TextureFormat. I think problem with reading (img dont taken full), but I check length with stop poing in VS.

Comment: About result, source img its this jpg file: [picture](https://imgur.com/a/G4r93xv)

Comment: To save a Texture, use EncodeToPNG or EncodeToJPG.

Comment: @yasirkula its my first step:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in ArraySegment.
When I try return byteImage.Array - its return full array (levelFileBytes).
My solution now:

```
        private byte[] GetSprite()
        {
            int length = GetNextInt();

            
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[length];
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                imageBytes[i] = levelFileBytes[byteIndex + i];
            }

            byteIndex += length;

            return imageBytes;
        }
```